# Uservoice classic widgets appears in production environment but doesn't appear in developpement environement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, uservoice

I got ruby on rails project that i just install in my localhost, this project contains some uservoice classic widgets. these widgets appear on the hosted project and whenever I try run `rails s`  in my localhost the project started without showing these widgest. when I try `rails s -e production`  th widgest appear on the project.

Can you please explain to me this issue ? and how can I let the widgest runs in developement environement while running `rails s`

Thank you

Comment: don't know the widget, but a couple of places to look for would be your initializers, something was created for this widgets? there should be some condition or option to start this on production and not on development. The widget uses enviroment variables? maybe there are just set on production. In theory dev and prod are the same with different settings for each side, it should be on your config folder, its really unusual to find features that don't work at all on dev by design.

Comment: nothing on the initializers folderabout these widgets just it's source code placed on the same pages where it should be appeared. about environement variables if you mean the environement variable of the OS nothing  to configure outside the project. Thank you for answering my issue

Comment: may you share the view that you shows widget? or if you are using a specific gem, please include the link here. Maybe, you could take a look your javascript/css if there is any condition to hide/show. You could use chrome console to detect the widget (ex: $('.widget')) and try to see if it is css issue.